# Allow CORS in wicket 6.20

Tags: java, cors, wicket

I'm facing an issue with CORS (Cross Origin Resources Sharing) in my wicket web application.
In a local network everything is OK. after deploying my web app online I got the error below in my browser console.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

How can I allow cross origin on my service?
I'm using wicket 6.20.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this way as suggested [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/wicket-users/201706.mbox/%3C2006811664.484361.1498643120378@mail.yahoo.com%3E):

```
getCurrentWebResponse().addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
```

Hope this helps solve your problem!

Comment: Didn't help. I had to allow it at wildfly level using filters. Thanks

Comment: You might consider adding your own answer to fix the issue pointed out, it might help someone in need!

Comment: @Salearnah could you post what you did to allow this with WildFly this is an issue I am currently trying to solve